# Installing AWS toolkit for eclipse juno EE for Web Developers

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, installation, eclipse-juno, toolkit

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for eclipse juno EE for Web Developers. Everything works fine until I reach the terms and conditions page where I have to accept the terms for installation. At this point, even when I select the option "I have read and agree the terms and conditions" The FINISH or the NEXT button is not enabled and I am not able to proceed further. 
I have tried it many times but cannot understand what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed aws toolkit for  Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 3.7 ("Indigo") and it worked for me. I followed the simple steps given here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html

They recommend "indigo" so my guess is incompatibility with "juno" but i am not sure. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey dont know what the issue was but its working good after I reinstalled it..thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with both eclipse 3.7 and 4.2, tried restarting, reinstalling multiple times but still ***Finish*** button was not getting enabled after accepting the license. Finally, instead of selecting all the modules I installed it in part and thankfully it worked.

My installation subset:

**First Subset**

    AWS SDK for Java
    AWS Simple Workflow Tools
    AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core

**Second Subset**

    Amazon DynamoDB Management
    Amazon EC2 Management
    Amazon RDS Management

**Third Subset**

    Amazon SimpleDB Management
    Amazon CloudFormation Tools
    AWS Elastic Beanstalk

I didn't install Android.
This process made it work for both Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It actually worked for me by re-installing Eclipse Juno and then installing the above again.

Answer (score 0):

if you update eclipse it should work. there was a bug that was hard to reproduce but apparently it was resolved.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277265

Answer (score 0):

Two more suggestions to get the Finish button enabled;

- restart eclipse (bug link suggests the addition of a new site/repo is the root issue)
- click checkbox 'Hide Items Already Installed' (bug link suspects mismatch of license list with components requiring licence read update stops button being enabled)

I also selected the above 'First Subset' per mprabhat - don't know if that was relevant.

One more note to speed you up: don't need to click on each licence / scroll to the bottom to enable the Finish button... since you probably did this already the first time through :)